# Parsing date-time into readable formats

Tags: sql

I have the following code that WORKS but I am unable to recreate because I do not understand WHY it works. If you plug it in w3schools it compiles successfully.

I do not understand how "1501532100" is parsed into a working date function. individually, I can see how dateadd() and format works, but why does it work the way it does and how can I reverse engineer the rest of the integers into proper dates?

```
SELECT FORMAT((dateadd(s, 1501532100, '1969-12-31 20:00')), 'MM.dd.yyy');

RETURNS: 07.31.2017
```

Comment: `DATEADD(interval, number, date)`, your interval here is `s - seconds`, number is `1501532100` and the date being `1969-12-31 20:00` all that does is just adds `1501532100` seconds to `1969-12-31 20:00`

Comment: Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Note the code here assumes you want to display the time in the EDT time zone (-4h) which is why the epoch is set to 8pm new year's eve. It would be off by an hour for any date that falls in the winter time.

Answer (score 1):

`dateadd` accepts 3 arguments: `interval`, `number` and `date`. When `interval` is `s`, it means that `number` will be treated as `seconds`, so it will add that many seconds to the `date` specified and return the result, which will then be displayed in the `MM.dd.yyy` format.

You can think of the first argument of `dateadd` as a measurement unit of the second one.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

`DATEADD(interval, number, date)`

interval here is `s - seconds`, 
number is `1501532100` 
date being `1969-12-31 20:00`

all that does is just adds `1501532100` seconds to `1969-12-31 20:00`